# Is there a way to grab the index of an object in a nested array if you don't know how nested it is

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, nested

For example, let's say you have the list `t = ["hi", "bye"]`

If I wanted to grab the index of `bye`, I would just do `t.index("bye")`  and that would get me `1`

But let's say I have `t = ["hi", ["good", "bye"]]`,  `t.index("bye")` will no longer work.

Is there some way to grab the index of an element in a nested list, such that nested lists can be easily indexed.

I.e. for `t = ["hi", ["good", "bye"]]`

```
t.index("bye") # Outputs [1][1] or something similar
```

I should mention that for my purposes, there will be no duplicate elements in any of my lists or sublists so there can only be one output.

Comment: There isn't one index to grab, only a *series* of indices from distinct objects. You'd have to write your own (recursive) code to search through the referenced objects. `t`, for example, has *no* idea where `"bye"` might be or how to descend into whatever objects it may reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to solve this:

```py
def find(lst, x):
    for i, l in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(l, (list, tuple)):
            f = find(l, x)
            if f:
                return (i,) + f
        elif l == x:
            return (i,)
    return False

a = ["hi", "bye"]
b = ["hi", ["good", "bye"]]

print(find(a, 'bye'))    # (1,)
print(find(b, 'bye'))    # (1, 1)
print(find(b, 'good'))   # (1, 0)
```

[Edit suggested by Achxy_]

Comment: You can make this support for tuple or any other iterable type by passing in a tuple of the types you want to match as the second argument into `isinstance` ie you can do `isinstance(l, (list, tuple))` and have the added support of using tuples **and** list here :D